# using minidom to parse xml

Tags: python, xml, minidom

Hi I have trouble understanding the minidom module for Python.

I have xml that looks like this:

```
<Show>
<name>Dexter</name>
<totalseasons>7</totalseasons>
<Episodelist>
<Season no="1">
<episode>
<epnum>1</epnum>
<seasonnum>01</seasonnum>
<prodnum>101</prodnum>
<airdate>2006-10-01</airdate>
<link>http://www.tvrage.com/Dexter/episodes/408409</link>
<title>Dexter</title>
</episode>
<episode>
<epnum>2</epnum>
<seasonnum>02</seasonnum>
<prodnum>102</prodnum>
<airdate>2006-10-08</airdate>
<link>http://www.tvrage.com/Dexter/episodes/408410</link>
<title>Crocodile</title>
</episode>
<episode>
<epnum>3</epnum>
<seasonnum>03</seasonnum>
<prodnum>103</prodnum>
<airdate>2006-10-15</airdate>
<link>http://www.tvrage.com/Dexter/episodes/408411</link>
<title>Popping Cherry</title>
</episode>
```

More pretty: http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=7926

And this is my python code trying to read from that:

```
xml = minidom.parse(urlopen("http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=7926"))
for episode in xml.getElementsByTagName('episode'):
    for node in episode.attributes['title']:
        print node.data
```

I can't get the actual episode data out as I want to get all the data from each episode. I've tried different variants but I can't get it to work. Mostly I get a `<DOM Element: asdasd>` back. I only care about the data inside each episode.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I cannot recommend the minidom at all; the DOM api was developed with less flexible languages than python in mind. Take a look at the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead, it is much more pythonic and makes a task like yours much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `episode` element has child-elements, including a `title` element. Your code, however, is looking for *attributes* instead.

To get text out of a minidom element, you need a helper function:

```
def getText(nodelist):
    rc = []
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc.append(node.data)
    return ''.join(rc)
```

And then you can more easily print all the titles:

```
for episode in xml.getElementsByTagName('episode'):
    for title in episode.getElementsByTagName('title'):
        print getText(title)
```

Answer (score 1):

`title` is not an attribute, its a tag.  An attribute is like `src` in `<img src="foo.jpg" />`

```
>>> parsed = parseString(s)
>>> titles = [n.firstChild.data for n in parsed.getElementsByTagName('title')]
>>> titles
[u'Dexter', u'Crocodile', u'Popping Cherry']
```

You can extend the above to fetch other details. [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) is better suited for this though. As you can see from the snippet above minidom is not that friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martijn Pieters who tipped me with the ElementTree API I solved this problem.

```
xml = ET.parse(urlopen("http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=7296"))
                print 'xml fetched..'
                for episode in xml.iter('episode'):
                    print episode.find('title').text
```

Thanks